# how do I prevent authcookie refresh in aspnet core web application for specific URLs

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, fetch-api

I have an aspnet core web application and have two actions which for some users are called on a short timer to provide notification of changes. Is there a way to prevent these actions from refreshing the auth cookie timeout either on the server side or via the js fetch call.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify more about the actual scenario and requirement? So that we can understand it better.

Comment: Sure, for the first action there is a table of data. The web application polls the web service to find out whether there is any new data. The second action is to provide administrators with urgent system notifications (for instance a severe service failure).